# Comma separated delimited values in MsgBox to own rows?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple problem for which I can't find a solution to. I can get values into a MsgBox in my code in Excel as for example: `aaaaaaaa, bbbbbbbb, cccccccc, dddddddd etc.` I would like to get the comma separated values from this MsgBox into cells starting from for example `C15, C16, C17, C18 etc.` as following:

```
C15: aaaaaaaa
C16: bbbbbbbb
C17: cccccccc
C18: dddddddd
C19: etc.
```

I can't find a solution to my problem although I have tried to Google an answer for a couple of hours. All help appreciated!

```
Sub ComSepList()
Dim lr As Long, rng As Range, c As Range, fLoc As Range
Dim fAdr As String, rngOut As Range
Dim xArr() As String
Dim tttt As String

lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Set rngOut = Range("C15")
Set rng = Range("B2:B" & lr)
    For Each c In rng
    'MsgBox c


Set fLoc = Range("A:A").Find(c.Value, , xlValues)
        If Not fLoc Is Nothing Then
            fAdr = fLoc.Address
            Do
                If fLoc.Offset(0, 6) = "1" Then
                    c.Offset(0, 4) = c.Offset(0, 4).Value & fLoc.Offset(0, 7).Value & ", "
                End If


fLoc.Value = c.Value
                Set fLoc = Range("A:A").FindNext(fLoc)
            Loop While fAdr <> fLoc.Address
            tttt = Left(c.Offset(0, 4).Value, Len(c.Offset(0, 4).Value) - 1)
        End If


    'Columns("F").AutoFit
    Next
    MsgBox tttt
    rngOut.Resize(UBound(Split(tttt.Text, ","))).Value = Application.Transpose(Split(tttt.Text, ","))
End Sub
```

Comment: Concatenation ?

Comment: Split the Value in your input on (I assume you mistyped Msgbox) on the comma. And resize cell C15 to write the returned array. It really is just a single line of code

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("C15").Resize(uBound(split(YourMsgBox.Text,","))+1).Value = Application.Transpose(split(YourMsgBox.Text,","))`

Comment: @ScottCraner your suggestion gives me an "Invalid qualifier" and can't execute code in break mode.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and show the code you have tried.

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks for your input but the code I just posted won't work applied with your input. I can't find what I do wrong.

Comment: A message box does not return a string.  Also, change `tttt.Text` to `tttt`

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information. Now I know this and now it seems to work almost as wanted. However there are white spaces (one for each cell value after the first one (C15)). Is there an easy way to tackle this problem so that there are no white spaces in front of the output cell values after C15? Probably an easy fix but my brain doesn't work as wanted now.

Comment: Sorry for the last message, I missed the "Application.Trim" part from the code. Now it works as wanted, thanks a lot @ScottCraner :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub kjlkjlkj()
    Dim t As String
    t = InputBox("String")

    ActiveSheet.Range("C15").Resize(UBound(Split(t, ",")) + 1).Value = _
        Application.Transpose(Application.Trim(Split(t, ",")))
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]